# shutdown system(windows 8.1) by system function in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("date");
    system("c:\\windows\\system32\\shutdown /r");
}
```

I tried this code to run a shutdown and display current date using `system()` library in C, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this program to shut down or turn off your Windows 7/8/8.1 PC.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
   char in;
   printf("Do you want to shutdown your computer now (y/n)\n");
   scanf("%c",&in);
   if (in == 'y' || in == 'Y')
      system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s");
   return 0;
}
```

The above code will shut down the system in 30 secs . 
To shutdown immediately use `"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\ shutdown /s /t 0"`. 
To restart use `/r instead of /s`

Comment: can you please tell me what's happening after you run the code? the above code will shut down the system in 30 secs . 
To shutdown immediately use "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\ shutdown /s /t 0". 
To restart use /r instead of /s.

Comment: nothing , if i add getch() then it was wait for a key press,
else just run and again came back to interface

Comment: how are you running the program in windows? i mean are you running the c program in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

just check whether you are giving the directory correctly or not.I mean check the caps lock as it is case sensitive

Comment: Windows is generally not case-sensitive, and I reckon it isn't in this specific case.